# SOQL, Salesforce - Join Two objects with two where clauses

Tags: sql, salesforce, soql

I have two objects named as 'Opportunity' and 'Account.
I need to select ID, OpportunityName,CreatedDate from Opportunity table and AccountName, AccountCat from Account table where Account.OpportunityID = Opportunity.ID and AccountCat = 'DC'.

I refer [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2013/05/basic-soql-relationship-queries.html) tutorial and executed in [workbench](https://workbench.developerforce.com/), but didn't work.

Following is the query I used.

```
SELECT AccountName, AccountCat (SELECT Id, OpportunityName,CreatedDate FROM Opportunity) FROM Account WHERE OpportunityID 
IN (SELECT Id FROM Opportunity) AND AccountCat = 'DC'
```

Answer (score 2):

Run your query on the Opportunity object and then use reference fields to select fields from the parent object.

```
SELECT  Id
    ,   Name
    ,   CreatedDate
    ,   Account.Name
FROM    Opportunity
WHERE   Account.Name = 'GenePoint'
```

`AccountCat` is not a standard field, so I assume it's a custom field, in which case you need to use the developer name, probably something like `Account.Cat__c` or `Account.Category__c` or something like that.

SOQL is superficially similar to SQL, but there are significant differences, one of them being how records are joined.